# How do I include this regular expression when creating an object?

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5.3

After my `$plates = explode(';', $plates);` i'd like to include another regular expression when creating a new `$dossier` (in my foreach):

`$minus = preg_replace('~[-]~', '', $license_plates);`

How would I do that?

This is my code:

```
public function addLicensePlates(Request $request)
{            
    $product_id = $request->input('product_id');

    $license_plates = $request->input('license_plates');

    $plates = preg_replace('~\s+|[.,:;*/_]~', ';', $license_plates); // \s+|[.,:;*/_]

    $plates = explode(';', $plates);

    foreach($plates as &$plate) {
        $dossier = new Dossier;
        $dossier->license_plate = trim($plate);
        $dossier->product_id = $product_id;
        $dossier->save();
    }
}
```

PS: I don't want to add the `-` to the `$plates` expression, but after the explode.

Comment: Add the `-` to the character class - `'~\s+|[.,:;*/_-]~'`.

Comment: Ehm, for specifically this object I don't want the `-` to explode. Therefore, I want a new regular expression after the explode.

Comment: Then, have you used your `preg_replace('~[-]~', '', $license_plates)`? What is the problem? Surely, a `str_replace` is better for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, but don't you have to call it like I did with `trim($plate)`?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you need, please provide a sample string and expected output.

Comment: When writing a function, I assume you also need to execute (call) it, right? So when creating a new `$dossier`, I want all license plates that are submitted in this format: '36-LXD-5', to be converted (and displayed) to 36LXD5 in my dossier index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest editing the existing function as follows:

- Use `trim()` on the input string when `preg_replace`ing to get rid of empty values later
- Use `str_replace` to replace the hyphens later in the `foreach` block.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/6IlBBS):

```
$license_plates = "  WORD-HERE 36-LXD-5";
$plates = preg_replace('~\s+|[.,:;*/_]~', ';', trim($license_plates)); // trim the incoming value
$plates = explode(';', $plates);
foreach($plates as &$plate) {
    $license_plate = str_replace('-', '', $plate); // Remove hyphens
    echo $license_plate. "\n";
}
```

Output: `WORDHERE` and `36LXD5`.